# LINQ: Group by aggregate but still get information from the most recent row?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a table that holds shipping history.  I'd like to write a query that counts the amount of shipments per user and gets the shipping name from the most recent entry in the table for that user.

Table structure for simplicity:
ShipmentID
MemberID
ShippingName
ShippingDate

How do I write a LINQ C# query to do this?

Comment: "per user" u mean memberID?
"most recent entry" -> shippingDate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like might want something like:

```
var query = from shipment in context.ShippingHistory
            group shipment by shipment.MemberID into g
            select new { Count = g.Count(),
                     MemberID = g.Key,
                     MostRecentName = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ShipmentDate)
                                       .First()
                                       .ShipmentName };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a LINQ answer, but *personally*, I'd be dropping to SQL for that, to make sure it isn't doing any N+1 etc; for example:

```
select s1.MemberID, COUNT(1) as [Count],
    (select top 1 ShippingName from Shipping s2 where s2.MemberID = s1.MemberID
     order by s2.ShippingDate desc) as [LastShippingName]
from Shipping s1
group by s1.MemberID
```

You can probably do LINQ something like (untested):

```
var qry = from row in data
          group row by row.MemberId into grp
          select new {
               MemberId = grp.Key,
               Count = grp.Count(),
               LastShippingName =
              grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.ShippingDate).First().ShippingName
           };
```